# Is this the right approach to this probability question?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Q: you kick 20 normal balls and 5 special balls at a goal. Each normal ball that goes in is worth 1 point, each special ball is worth 2 points. Your accuracy is 70%. What's the probability of scoring > 27 points?**

So, I calculated the average $(0.7 \times 20) \times 1 + (0.7 \times 5) \times 2$ to get 21 average points.

Then, I put these values into the Poisson distribution formula (assumed mean = variance). Therefore, $P(X=27) = 0.0349$.

However, I'm not sure how to show that it's greater than 27, just the probability of scoring exactly 27 points. And, I'm not sure if Poisson distribution is the best way to solve the answer? Clarification much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how to work with averages in this context.  I'd do it by cases, working off the number of special points scored.

Comment: Just to stress the problem with averages:  suppose $24$ of the balls were worth one point and the last is worth a trillion.  then the average is very, very high (roughly $700$ billion) but your probability of success is just $.7$ as the only relevant thing is whether you score the big points or not.

Comment: there are 3 cases to think about for number of points scored but many ways to do them probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson distribution is not relevant here.

There are only a small number of ways to get more than $27$ points:

- don't miss with any ball
- miss with one ball (it can be normal or special)
- miss with two normal balls only

You can work out the probability of each case separately, and add them. For example, the number of ways of missing with two normal balls only is
$${}^{20}\mathrm C_2\times 0.7^{23}\times 0.3^2$$
since there are ${}^{20}\mathrm C_2$ ways to choose the two balls, and each choice has probability $0.7^{23}\times 0.3^2$ (since you miss two and score 23).

(If you wanted $27$ or more there are two more cases - see the original version of my answer.)

Comment: For others who are not familiar with the notation OP used here (as I was not): by $\phantom{.}^{20}C_2$ s/he means $20$ choose $2$, AKA $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}20\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, AKA $\frac{20!}{(2!)(20-2)!}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $i=1,\dots, 20$ let  $X_i\sim BER(p=0.7)$ be the indicator variable that the $i$-th normal ball scores. Similar let $Y_j \sim BER(p=0.7)$, $j=1,\dots, 5$ be the indicator variable for a single score of a special ball. One may denote the total scores (not the points!) from the special balls by $Y= \sum_{j=1}^5 Y_j$ while $X=\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i$ are the scores from a normal Ball.

Assuming independence, note that $$X=\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i \sim BIN(20,0.7)$$ as well as  $$\sum_{j=1}^5 Y_j \sim BIN(5,0.7).$$

The total *POINTS* scored by the two balls, may then be defined as
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i + 2\sum_{j=1}^5 Y_j = X+2Y.$$
$T$ takes values in $\{0,1,2,\dots,30\}$.

We search
\begin{align*}
P(\{T>27\}) &= P(\{T=28\} \cup \{T=29\} \cup \{T=30\}) \\
           &=P(\{T=28\}) + P(\{T=29\}) + P(\{T=30\}).
\end{align*}

Now note that $$\{T=28\} \Leftrightarrow (\{X=20\} \cap 
\{Y=4\}) \cup (\{X=18\} \cap \{Y=5\})$$
Hence 
\begin{align*}
P(\{T=28\}) &= P((\{X=20\} \cap 
\{Y=4\}) \cup (\{X=18\} \cap \{Y=5\}))\\
&= P(\{X=20\} \cap 
\{Y=4\}) + P(\{X=18\} \cap \{Y=5\})\\
&=P(\{X=20\})P(\{Y=4\}) +P(\{X=18\})P(\{Y=5\}).
\end{align*}
With similar observations we obtain
\begin{align*}
P(\{T=29\}) &= P(\{X=19\} \cap 
\{Y=5\}) = P(\{X=19\})P(\{Y=5\}),
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
P(\{T=30\}) &= P(\{X=20\} \cap 
\{Y=5\}) = P(\{X=20\})P(\{Y=5\}).
\end{align*}

The involved probabilities are easily calculated from the fact that $X\sim BIN(20,0.7)$ and $Y\sim BIN(5,0.7)$, since we have for a $BIN(n,p)$ distributed random variabe $W$: $$P(W=k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-p},$$ if $k\in\{0,1,\dots, n\}$.

---

In more complicated cases you may calculate similar probabilities by conditioning. Indeed, since $$\{T>27\} \Leftrightarrow \bigcup_{k=0}^5\{T>27\} \cap \{Y=k\},$$
we have:
\begin{align*}
P(T>27) &= \sum_{k=0}^5 P(T>27|Y=k)P(Y=k)\\
        &= \sum_{k=0}^5 P(X>27-2k|Y=k)P(Y=k)\\
        &= \sum_{k=0}^5 P(X>27-2k)P(Y=k)\\
        &= P(X>19)P(Y=4) + P(X>17)P(Y=5)
\end{align*}

Where it was used that $P(X>27-2k|Y=k) = P(X>27-2k)$, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

---

Both approaches will yield a probability of $0.006251022$.

Rcode:

(first approach)

> nx = 20; ny = 5;p = 0.7
>
> (dbinom(20,nx,p)*dbinom(4,ny,p) + dbinom(18,nx,p)*dbinom(5,ny,p))+
>   (dbinom(19,nx,p)*dbinom(5,ny,p))+
>   (dbinom(20,nx,p)*dbinom(5,ny,p))

Results in [1] 0.006251022

(second approach)

> (1-pbinom(19,20,0.7))*dbinom(4,5,0.7)+ (1-pbinom(17,20,0.7))*dbinom(5,5,0.7)

Results in [1] 0.006251022

Comment: Right, thanks for the response. If I used the Binomial distribution formula (p = .7, n = 30), and add together the answers from P(X = 28), P(X = 29), P(X = 30), then I get 0.00211334. This is less than your answer, so can you explain why my method doesn't work? I used n = 30 because 30 points is the maximum you can get.

Comment: you used the wrong distribution in your calculations. As it is written above, $X$ is $BIN(20,p)$ and $Y$ is $BIN(5,p)$. on the other side: the total points $T$ are **not** binomial distributed. 

$n$ is the number of bernoulli trials. For $X$ you have $n_X=20$ and for $Y$ you have $n_Y=5$.

You then have, for example, $$P(T=30) = P(X=20)P(Y=5) = 0.0007979227 \cdot  0.16807 = 0.0001341069. $$

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, is this the correct logic then? E.g. for P(T = 30) = .7^20 x (1-.7)^20-20 x 20C20 multiplied by .7^5 x (1-.7)^5-5 x 5C5? My last confusion, then, is whether the 5's in the second part should be 5 or 10 (since 10 is the max number of points). Could you confirm whether it's 5 or 10?

Comment: the calculation is correct. I defined $T= X+2Y$, where  $Y$ is the number of *"hits"* obtained from 5 special balls - you have 5 special balls, hence  $Y$ is $BIN(5,0.7)$. hence, the 5 is correct. 

By multiplying $Y$ with 2 you get the total number of *points* scored from the special balls (each "hit" counts two points)...in my decomposition you express the number of points equivalently in terms of the number of hits.